# PHPMailer pagina en blanco

Tags: php, phpmailer

Llevo toda la tarde configurando el PHPMailer y no hay manera. Cuando le doy a enviar email, se queda la página en blanco. Y no envía nada.

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST["firstname"];  
$correo = $_POST["correo"];  
$mensaje = $_POST["subject"];  

$body = "Nombre: " . $nombre . <br>"Correo: " . $correo . <br>"Asunto: " .$mensaje;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'micorreo@correo.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'micontraseña';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($correo, $nombre);
    $mail->addAddress('micorreo@correo.com');     //Add a recipient

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Correo desde el blog';
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

?>
```

Tampoco me salen los mensajes de excepción, ni el debug. Lo había probado a poner a 1 por si las moscas, pero nada de nada.

Comment: Pon el nivel de debug a 4 temporalmente, así podrás ver cualquier tipo de posible problema: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;`

Comment: Buenas tardes A. Cedano muchas gracias por contestar :) Acabo de probar y la pagina se me sigue quedando en blanco. :S

Comment: ¿Qué muestra si pones un `var_dump($_POST);` al inicio del archivo? Por otra parte, tus `use` y `require` juntos son redundantes.